# TCP : reverse echo client throws an error message on Linux (written in C )

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, tcpclient

Already have the server running on the another terminal.

Would this be an issue with Linux?

Echo error message on the client terminal:

[image]

Comment: You cannot use any address in the `127.0.0.0/8` address range on any network outside the host. Any traffic sent to an address in that range immediately loops back inside the hot. Per the RFCs from very early on, no address in that range is allowed to appear in any network anywhere.

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures... next time, please paste the code / messages into your question.

Comment: @skatehead A client can connect to `127.0.0.1` only if the server is running on the same machine as the client. Are you running multiple terminals on the same machine, or on different machines?

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah I was running the client and server on different terminals

Comment: @skatehead different terminals **on the same machine** will work fine. The client can connect to `127.0.0.1` if the server is listening on either `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1`.